# Weird output when specifying GL_RGBA32F in glTexImage2D()

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I'm working on a Java (JOGL) program to conduct some computation with shader programs, and I'm experiencing weird output values from a fragment shader.
More specifically, it seems that glGetTexImage() returns scaled values.

Now, here is a simple fragment shader.

```
#version 330

layout(location=0) out vec4 fs_out_color;

void main(){
    fs_out_color=vec4(-1.0,0.5,0.4,2.0);
}
```

I create a floating-point texture to get the output from the shader. 
TEXTURE_WIDTH and TEXTURE_HEIGHT are both 2.

```
glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glTexImage2D(
        GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL4.GL_RGBA32F, 
        TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL4.GL_RGBA, GL4.GL_FLOAT, null);
glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL4.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL4.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

GL_RGBA32F is passed to the third argument of glTexImage2D() to get the values that are not clamped.

Then, the results are fetched with the following code:

```
int size=TEXTURE_WIDTH*TEXTURE_HEIGHT*4;
FloatBuffer buf=Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(size);

glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glGetTexImage(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL4.GL_RGBA, GL4.GL_FLOAT, buf);
glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

And finally, they are output to the console.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i+=4) {
    float r=buf.get();
    float g=buf.get();
    float b=buf.get();
    float a=buf.get();

    String str="("+r+","+g+","+b+","+a+")";
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

What I expect here is something like `(-1.0,0.5,0.4,2.0)`.
However, the actual output is

```
(-2.0,1.0,0.8,4.0)
(-2.0,1.0,0.8,4.0)
(-2.0,1.0,0.8,4.0)
(-2.0,1.0,0.8,4.0)
```

I tried another vec4 variable `vec4(-10.0,0.5,0.4,20.0)` in the shader, and I got

```
(-200.0,10.0,8.0,400.0)
(-200.0,10.0,8.0,400.0)
(-200.0,10.0,8.0,400.0)
(-200.0,10.0,8.0,400.0)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? How can I get the original output of the fragment shader?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Note:
Fragment shader

```
fs_out_color=vec4(-1.0,0.5,0.4,2.0);
```

Java code

```
glTexImage2D(
        GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL4.GL_RGBA, 
        TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL4.GL_RGBA, GL4.GL_FLOAT, null);
```

and the output is

```
(0.0,0.5019608,0.4,1.0)
(0.0,0.5019608,0.4,1.0)
(0.0,0.5019608,0.4,1.0)
(0.0,0.5019608,0.4,1.0)
```

Seems to work well with GL_RGBA.

Comment: Yes, the texture is attached to a framebuffer and I render to it with glDrawElements().

Comment: I happened to come back after 5 months and reviewed this question, for nothing.

I applied unnecessary changes to the code before posting.
Actual calls to OpenGL functions look like:
`GL4 gl = GLContext.getCurrentGL().getGL4();
gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
`

Just to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's do some more or less educated guesswork:

```
Input: -1.0,0.5,0.4,2.0   -> Output: -2.0,1.0,0.8,4.0
Input: -10.0,0.5,0.4,20.0 -> Output: -200.0,10.0,8.0,400.0 
Input: -1.0,0.5,0.4,2.0   -> Output: 0.0,0.5019608,0.4,1.0  (using UNORM target)
```

Hypothesis: you have  [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) enabled, and you have especially set `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, ...)` so that your fragment shader's output (which will be the source operand for the blending stage) will be multiplied by the alpha value you provide. Note that when using an UNORM render target like `GL_RGBA`, the fragment shader's output will be clamped to `[0,1]` before the blending will happen, so you get alpha = 1.0 in there, and the multiplication has no effect.

If my hypothesis is correct, you would also get "wrong" scaled results in the UNORM `GL_RGBA` format case if you tried with input alpha  of 0.5.

Comment: This is a perfect answer for me.
I have blending enabled and set glBlendFunc(GL4.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL4.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).

Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Note that this is also a case of _undefined values_. Since you create the texture with `NULL` as the data pointer, the texture contents are _uninitialized_, and you add (well, sort of, 1-alpha is negative in your scenarios, so you subtract) them as the destination factor during blending. However, there is a big chance that your texture is all zeros in real world situations, but that is not guaranteed by the spec.